# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: r is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, typeerror

I have a problem with prod build. Everything fine when I deploy it, I can visit the site, but two pages gives me an TypeError: r is not a function. I have been looking through a lot of issues on github and other sites, but din't find anything helpful.
[Here is the error (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dtds.jpg)

I'm using webpack 3.10.0, babel 6.23.0, node 8.9

Here is webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    //const isDevBuild = true;
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/', // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
            path: './wwwroot/',
            chunkFilename: 'dist/[id].chunk.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/, use: "babel-loader?cacheDirectory" },
                //{ test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular-router-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular-router-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'] : ['angular-router-loader?aot=true', '@ngtools/webpack'] },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] },
                { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize', 'sass-loader'] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module#AppModule')
                    , sourceMap: true
                })
            ])
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig];
};
```

And webpack.vendor.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'core-js/client/shim',
    'web-animations-js',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
    'screenfull',
    '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css',
    'ng2-toasty',
    'ng2-toasty/bundles/style-bootstrap.css',
    'ng2-charts',
    'ngx-bootstrap/modal',
    'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip',
    'ngx-bootstrap/popover',
    'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown',
    'ngx-bootstrap/carousel',
    'bootstrap-vertical-tabs/bootstrap.vertical-tabs.css',
    'bootstrap-toggle/css/bootstrap-toggle.css',
    'bootstrap-toggle/js/bootstrap-toggle.js',
    'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css',
    'bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js',
    'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css',
    'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
    './ClientApp/app/styles-external.css'
];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    //const isDevBuild = true;
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js'] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(gif|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]',
            path: './wwwroot/',
            chunkFilename: 'dist/[id].[hash].chunk.js'
        },
        plugins: [
            //new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
                'window.Tether': 'tether',
                tether: 'tether',
                Tether: 'tether'
            }),
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(@angular|esm5)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
            // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I took a step far back and saw my mistake. I used UglyfyJS to decrease size of js files in production deployment and didn't notice, that the current version was not compatible with TS version, so, in my case, the right thing to do was to install UglyfyJS harmony and remove babel-loader. And after that when I imported all the stuff it started to work well.